# C# project with powershell import-module Configuration Manager

Tags: c#, powershell, configurationmanager, sccm

I'm creating this C# project with Powershell integration. Its working fine with importing modules like ActiveDirectory.

But i cannot get it working with Configuration Manager, does not throw and error, but with 'Get-PSDrive' the result does not show the ConfMgr Sitecode, like in the normal Powershell window, only the other drives from a normal Get-PSDrive command.

I have tried both x64 and x86 versions of the application, with and without admin rigths.

Can anyone tell me what the problem may be?

Code:

```
        try
        {
            InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1" });
            //initial.ImportPSModulesFromPath(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1");

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
            runspace.Open();

            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            runspace.Close();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
```

Best Regards
Thomas Nissen

Comment: Are you able to import the module from a standard PowerShell window?

Comment: Yes, 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Configura
tionManager.psd1"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-Location GOH:
PS GOH:\> Get-CMSite

SmsProviderObjectPath       : SMS_Site.SiteCode="GOH"
BuildNumber                 : 8498
Features                    : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
InstallDir                  : D:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager
Mode                        : 0
ReportingSiteCode           :
RequestedStatus             : 110

Comment: does it work if you do it like: using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create()) {
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"Import-Module '" + sccmPSModulePath + "'");
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("cd <sitecode>:");
                PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
} I only ever once used sccm powershell cmdlets from c# (too slow imo) but I did it like this and it worked (needs System.Management.Automation.dll but so does probably your approach)